# Get-GPO: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I've been trying to count how many GPO files in DCs From DC-A to DC-B ( They are in a trusted domain) . I got this error:

```
Get-GPO : Value does not fall within the expected range.
At C:\Temp\HealthCheck\ADReplication.ps1:70 char:18
+     $gpoCount = (Get-GPO -all -Server $dc).count
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-GPO], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.GetGpoCommand
```

it works with other dcs, but few of them getting this error. I wish to know why it happens and to have a solution for this.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the working and non-working DCs in different domains?

Comment: I tried to run this in different domain and I got this error. When I run it in the same domain the it works just fine. Do you think it obstructed by some credential needed?

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting errors when using `DomainA\User` to run the `Get-GPO` command on a DC for `DomainB`? If so, is it in a shared forest, or between a trusted pair of domains? Please update the question with this info.

Comment: @CoryKnutson You'r right, Edited!. I also got an answer that it's not able to query the GPO from the Domain A to Domain B.

Comment: Are you able to view Group Policy objects from the other domain through the GUI console?

Comment: @CoryKnutson Yes, I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only exception to this rule is cross-domain GPOs where a GPO is defined in another domain, but is linked in such a way that clients from neighboring domains need to apply them (a Site-level GPO is an example, since Active Directory Sites can span multiple domains).  In the case of a cross-domain GPO, the client will need to pull content from a DC in the neighboring domain which can be a very slow process.  For this reason, cross-domain GPOs are not generally recommended - From [TechNet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/musings_of_a_technical_tam/2012/02/13/group-policy-basics-part-1-understanding-the-structure-of-a-group-policy-object/)

Answer (score 0):

This is reproducible in my environment to a trusted domain. I do not have a direct fix, but would this be usable for you? This would require having credentials to the remote forest, but I would assume that you would have them.

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $cred -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Get-GPO -All}
```

Comment: Thanks. Due to security issue, I don't really want to address any credential :).